# MatLab picture location in another picture

Tags: image, matlab, matlab-figure

I'm trying to make a visual stimuli task and I wanted to pick four locations of size 200x200 px in a 1000x1000px image that I will substitute by a 200x200px image. Is it possible without any matrix substitution?

Comment: could you please show us what your code looks so far?

Comment: It would be very simple to achieve this using matrix substitution; why do you not want to do this? Example: `Image1000(5+(1:200),8+(1:200)) = Image200`.